# How to parse the String array into image using java?

Tags: java, string, image, byte

Hi could any explain me how to parse the String hex decimal array into an image as below. This data I am getting from the server and I am converting that into the hex String.

```
     String sb = "0d 02 01 02 4e 52 30 39 47 30 35 36 31 38 00 03 00 fa 01 95 \n"
                            + "e4 53 c0 a8 51 b1 53 a3 03 40 89 54 66 9c ee 10 01 de 9a 5c \n"
                            + "22 e6 a0 2c 5d b2 69 8c 9d 79 e6 a5 41 50 c6 78 ab 31 8c 8a \n"
                            + "00 72 83 53 2a e0 67 14 d0 2a 54 1b 85 00 00 76 a6 b4 64 1e \n"
                            + "95 32 a1 c8 a5 90 f3 81 da 98 15 88 c7 51 54 6e 63 cb 1e 3a \n"
                            + "d6 99 19 19 ef 55 6e 13 2b 91 49 89 98 2f a7 49 b8 95 20 8a \n"
                            + "88 d9 cc b9 f9 0d 6d 85 e6 9e 23 e3 a5 06 7c a6 02 c6 e8 c3 \n"
                            + "2a 72 0d 74 90 1d d1 29 f5 14 cf 29 5b 82 01 fa 8a 9d 14 00 \n"
                            + "00 e0 50 38 ad 46 4c 38 15 89 7a b8 9c fa 11 5b f2 2e 56 a9 \n"
                            + "5c e9 ad 39 0e 18 03 8e f4 8a 68 c4 14 d2 39 ad 07 d2 ae 17 \n"
                            + "a0 0d f4 35 5d ed 27 4f bd 1b 0f c2 99 9d 88 06 41 ae 9f 4e \n"
                            + "19 b2 88 fb 57 36 54 83 c8 23 eb c5 74 da 70 c5 94 7f 4a 07 \n"
                            + "1d cb 2c 3e 53 58 77 1c ca 45 6e 37 dd 35 89 38 fd e9 a1 97 \n"
                            + "2d 88 76 d1 8a 76 29 c8 bb 98 52 32 23 da 4f 6a 96 38 01 19 \n"
                            + "6e 95 21 c0 e0 0a 98 0d d1 0c 75 14 0a c4 b6 d1 a0 8f 81 8c \n"
                            + "d3 9d 76 1a 92 24 21 00 a8 e7 38 fc 29 9b c7 62 85 c9 dc f8 \n"
                            + "f4 aa f8 a7 bb 65 89 a6 1e b4 8c a5 ab 0a 43 41 a6 f7 a0 43 \n"
                            + "5e 95 54 e0 50 06 48 06 a4 c7 14 0e 28 85 86 2a 32 78 a9 5e \n"
                            + "a0 90 e0 52 35 7b 12 e2 81 4b 8e 69 71 4c 60 bd 6a 74 a8 50 \n"
                            + "73 53 31 c0 da 3a d0 00 cd b8 e0 74 14 a0 8c e3 bd 20 18 1c \n"
                            + "75 a6 a9 cb 8d c3 9c d3 02 c4 7c 1a b8 83 8a aa 8a 59 b8 ab \n"
                            + "89 c0 02 80 1e 38 a5 52 41 e2 90 0a 51 40 0f f3 1b 34 ed e1 \n"
                            + "ba f5 a8 a9 71 40 12 16 e3 02 a2 75 ca 9a 78 a5 c1 34 01 45 \n"
                            + "46 3a d4 8b 43 ae d9 0f bd 0b 40 89 00 14 f0 05 31 4d 48 a2 \n"
                            + "81 8e db 9a 70 5a 45 19 a9 00 a6 16 1a 12 83 1e 6a 40 29 c1 \n"
                            + "68 15 91 58 db 46 df 79 14 fe 15 24 71 88 d7 6a 8c 01 da a6 \n"
                            + "c5 21 5a 01 22 0d 0a 2a 4b 57 00 0f 00 01 82 03 00 00 0d 0a ";
                   String raw_DeviceId = sb.substring(37, 1040);

            byte[] b = hexStringToByteArray(raw_DeviceId);
                    /*
                     * Converting Image byte array into Base64 String 
                     */
                    String imageDataString = encodeImage(b);

                    /*
                     * Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array 
                     */
                    byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);

                    /*
                     * Write a image byte array into file system  
                     */
                    FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("D:/img2.jpg");
                    imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);

                    imageInFile.close();
                    imageOutFile.close();

                    System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
                }

            }

            /**
             * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
             *
             * @param imageByteArray - byte array
             * @return String a {@link java.lang.String}
             */
            public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
                return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
            }

            /**
             * Decodes the base64 string into byte array
             *
             * @param imageDataString - a {@link java.lang.String}
             * @return byte array
             */
            public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
                return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
            }

        }
```

Updated: code

I have Used this code to convert hexStringToByteArray but it giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range.

```
 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
            int len = s.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            System.out.println("data = " + data.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: What do you believe that `String.getBytes()` does, and what do you really want it to do?

Comment: Here I have the Hex String I want to get the image by convert into byte array

Comment: And is that what `String.getBytes()` does? (Hint: search for "parse hex bytes java" within Stack Overflow...)

Comment: String.getBytes() by using this I am getting bytes

Comment: Yes you are getting bytes, but the byte representation of the String. not the actual Hex values themselves. These will both return different byte arrays

Comment: How to Do that Plz give some hint

Comment: Please learn to use the search:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: String raw_DeviceId = sb.substring(37, 1040);

 byte[] b =hexStringToByteArray(raw_DeviceId);

Comment: public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1003

Comment: please tell me whts the problem with above code I am getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @user3475175 Please edit your question with your recent trials instead of posting them as comments.

Comment: I have updated my question please look at.

Comment: The method hexString2ByteArray assumes even number of digits from the input string which is 2 digit per byte. Your input is not in this format since you have a lot spaces there and the sub-string you passed into the method has a odd number length